# Elegant Numpy Tensor product

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, numpy-einsum

I need to take the product over two tensors in numpy (or pytorch):

I have

```
A = np.arange(1024).reshape(8,1,128)
B = np.arange(9216).reshape(8, 128, 9)
```

And want to obtain `C`, with dot products summing over the last dim of `A` (`axis=2`) and the middle dim of `B` (`axis=1`). This should have dimensions `8x9`. Currently, I am doing:

```
C = np.zeros([8, 9])
for i in range(8):
    C[i,:] = np.matmul(A[i,:,:], B[i,:,:])
```

**How to do this elegantly?**

I tried:

```
np.tensordot(weights, features, axes=(2,1)).
```

but it returns `8x1x8x9`.

Comment: The code you've provided for what you're currently doing does not compute C. What is `cam`? How does it relate to `C`?

Comment: `np.matmul(A, B)` should produce (8,1,9)

Comment: @AlexanderGuyer `cam=C`. I fixed that. sorry. I want to get the dot product over dim 2 of A and dim 1 of B. If I ignore the first axis, that is a matrix product isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use [`numpy.einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html).

```py
C = np.einsum('ijk,ikl->il', A, B)
```

Or you could use [broadcasted](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/theory.broadcasting.html) matrix multiply.

```py
C = (A @ B).squeeze(axis=1)
# equivalent: C = np.matmul(A, B).squeeze(axis=1)
```